# room map game program reading from a file

Tags: c++

These are the directions: this file represents the game map for our interactive fiction game Specifcally, the first line contains the number of rooms on the map and each successive line represents each of these rooms; one line is one room. As such, the number on the first line should equal the number of lines below it in the file. The first line after the number of rooms is 1 and goes on from there. Each room line contains four numbers. These are the rooms that the current room connects to up, down, left and right, respectively. So, since Room 3 is listed as 3 4 2 10, it connects up, down, left and right to Room 3, Room 4, Room 2 and Room 10, respectively. To move to another room you can access from the room you pick you pick either up,down,left,right. I am not asking for anyone todo this AT ALL!!!. i am trying to get help with starting the program. I am stuck with how to start this program, i don't know how i would get the numbers and represent each column to u,d,l,r also and how do i print out those number for the line you picked? this is all i have so far but idk where to go from here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char room;
    int room1;
    string room; 
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("GameFile.txt")
    while (infile.is_open())
    infile.getline(infile,line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your question is about a specific part, I reccomend you delete all other unneccesary information from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like a quadruply linked list (i just made up this term). So I would just define a struct:

```
struct Room {
    int up;
    int down;
    int left;
    int right;
};
```

overload the input operator and push them line by line into a `std::vector<Room>`. Otherwise there is little help to offer given the information you provide.